# Button visible based on team

Tags: dynamics-crm

Button should visible Based on the team.Example If logged-in user part of the "Test Team","Test Button" should be enable.If not disable.I am using webapi .But it is giving null values.Any suggestions??

```
 function GetUserTeam() {
var clientUrl1 = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
var oDataPath1 = clientUrl1 + "/api/data/v8.0/";
var req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
   try {

    var strTest = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>" +
                    "  <entity name='team'>" +
                    "    <attribute name='name' />" +
                    "    <attribute name='businessunitid' />" +
                    "    <attribute name='teamid' />" +
                    "    <attribute name='teamtype' />" +
                    "    <order attribute='name' descending='false' />" +
                    "    <filter type='and'>" +
                    "      <condition attribute='teamtype' operator='eq' value='0' />" +
                    "    </filter>" +
                    "    <link-entity name='teammembership' from='teamid' to='teamid' visible='false' intersect='true'>" +
                    "      <link-entity name='systemuser' from='systemuserid' to='systemuserid' alias='ab'>" +
                    "        <filter type='and'>" +
                    "          <condition attribute='systemuserid' operator='eq-userid' />" +
                    "        </filter>" +
                    "      </link-entity>" +
                    "    </link-entity>" +
                    "  </entity>" +
                    "</fetch>";
    req1.open("GET", oDataPath1 + "teams?fetchXml=" + encodeURI(strTest), true);
    req1.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req1.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req1.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req1.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            // debugger;
            req1.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status == 200) {
                var reqResults = JSON.parse(this.response).value;
                if (reqResults != null && reqResults.length > 0) {
                    if ("TestTeam"==reqResults.length[i].name){return true;}

                else{return false;}
                }
                    }//End of for

                }//En of IF

            }

            else {

                var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
                alert(error.message);
            }

        }

    };      
    req1.send();              

}
catch (e) {

    alert(e);

}

}
```

Comment: This is certainly something that can be accomplished in Dynamics.  Show your code that is giving null values.

Comment: I got return value .But button is not disable/enable ,when I call this function using Ribbon button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your sample code.  It had some syntax errors, but I assume this is because you edited it for the post.  For example, the for loop wasn't present and brackets were missing.

1. The request is asynchronous.  Undefined was returned from  your method.  You either want to change the XMLHttpRequest to run synchronously (generally not recommended for user experience reasons) or pass in callbacks to call when you have a result.  Here I added onSuccess and onError.  onSuccess would take true/false as an argument which is whether or not TestTeam was found.
2. In your for loop you had reqResults.length[i] where you maybe meant reqResults[i].  Again, that could be just an issue with editing for posting.

So this code will call onSuccess with a value of true if TestTeam is one of the user's teams.  With false if not.  Or it will call onError if an error occurs.  You might edit to build an array of teams to pass back, etc.  Or you can edit the .open() call so it runs [synchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) and doesn't use callbacks.

```
function GetUserTeam(onSuccess, onError) {
    var clientUrl1 = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var oDataPath1 = clientUrl1 + "/api/data/v8.0/";
    var req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try {

        var strTest = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>" +
                        "  <entity name='team'>" +
                        "    <attribute name='name' />" +
                        "    <attribute name='businessunitid' />" +
                        "    <attribute name='teamid' />" +
                        "    <attribute name='teamtype' />" +
                        "    <order attribute='name' descending='false' />" +
                        "    <filter type='and'>" +
                        "      <condition attribute='teamtype' operator='eq' value='0' />" +
                        "    </filter>" +
                        "    <link-entity name='teammembership' from='teamid' to='teamid' visible='false' intersect='true'>" +
                        "      <link-entity name='systemuser' from='systemuserid' to='systemuserid' alias='ab'>" +
                        "        <filter type='and'>" +
                        "          <condition attribute='systemuserid' operator='eq-userid' />" +
                        "        </filter>" +
                        "      </link-entity>" +
                        "    </link-entity>" +
                        "  </entity>" +
                        "</fetch>";
        req1.open("GET", oDataPath1 + "teams?fetchXml=" + encodeURI(strTest), true);
        req1.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req1.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        req1.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req1.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                // debugger;
                req1.onreadystatechange = null;
                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        var returnValue = false;
                        var reqResults = JSON.parse(this.response).value;
                        if (reqResults != null && reqResults.length > 0) {
                            for(var i = 0, j = reqResults.length; i < j; i++){
                                if ("TestTeam" == reqResults[i].name){
                                    returnValue = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Call the handler
                        onSuccess && onSuccess(returnValue);
                    }
                    else {
                        var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
                        alert(error.message);
                        onError && onError(error);
                    }
            }
        };      
        req1.send();
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
        onError && onError(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late replay .Thank you very much ,I just modified u r code. Now I can able to hide/show button.Please find below points.
I have declared one global varibale .like var teamValu=false;
then i wrote separate function[usehasTeam].In that I am checking teamvalue is null or undefined , setTimeout(usehasTeam,500).if Not null ,I have called "usehasTeam" in ribbon enable rules.